# How to make Pywinauto in Python click a button in a different language?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

I just can't get Pywinauto to work.
Basically I want it to open the system settings ( figured that out already) and then click "Change Settings" but in my language (German) which would be "Einstellungen ändern".
I've tried this:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application, keyboard 
from pywinauto.application import Application 

app = Application().start("control system") 
#so far it works, after that I've tried two options 
#1  
app.window_(title_re="System").window_(title="Einstellungen ändern").click()
#2
app.window_(best_match="System" ).window_(best_match="Einstellungen ändern").click()
```

I've tried both of these options with the AutomationId, which I got from Inspect.exe, instead of "System" or "Einstellungen ändern" and I've tried `ClickInput()` instead of `click()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Default backend is `"win32"` which relies to Spy++. If you're using `Inspect.exe`, use `Application(backend="uia")` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues:

- Correct backend is `"uia"` that must be specified for `Application` object.
- Launcher process spawns a subprocess which requires to reconnect to this child process.

This code works for my English Win10:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application 

app = Application(backend="uia").start("control system")
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="System", timeout=20)

app.window(title="System").child_window(title="Change settings").invoke()
# app.window(title="System").child_window(title="Einstellungen ändern").invoke()
```

`.click_input()` should work as well. Backend `"uia"` defines method `.click()` as an alias of `.invoke()` for `control_type="Button"` only, because InvokePattern can have different meaning for various control types.

---

NOTE: After clicking on "Change settings" the appeared "System properties" window is running inside another process which requires method `.connect()` again and maybe separate `Application` instance for your convenience.

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally works now :) is there an easy way to figure out when a sub/child process is spawned, so i know when i have to reconnect?

Comment: Inspect.exe shows process ID for every element/window. For example, Win10 Calculator has few processes for one window. Yeah, even such crazy things are possible. We have plans to implement spawned child process detection for next major release.